# Loading page with timer - HTML/PHP

Tags: loading

How would i go about making a Loading page in HTML/PHP with a simple Gif, with a timer, which then redirects to another page after say 5 seconds.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe this [Javascript redirect Tutorial](http://www.code-sucks.com/code/javascript/template.php?tutorial=redirect_with_timer.php) can help you.

Comment: Thanks, but this is what i was looking for: Thanks, but this is what i was looking for:

   


<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="seconds;URL=the-other-url">

Comment: link is defunct, can @moderator remove post